# Offset first post WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to offset the first post as I am displaying it above so there is no need it to be included in the loop too but my offset dosnt seem to want to work:

**Attempt 1:**

```
<?php 
    // the query
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 
                                        'post_status'=>'publish', 
                                        'posts_per_page => -1&offset = 1'

    )); ?>

    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 
                                    'post_status'=>'publish', 
                                    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                                    'offset' => 1
)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

But still show the 'latest' in the loop still? Has anyone else had this issue or know what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

So it turns out that in the end it was to do with the amount of posts per page so I amended it to be:

```
        <?php 
        // the query
        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 
                                            'post_status'=>'publish',
                                            'posts_per_page'=> 10, // As per the post below you need to have a set number of posts.
                                            'offset' => 1
        )); ?>

        <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) the `offset` parameter is ignored when `posts_per_page` is set to `-1`.

> **offset (int)** - number of post to displace or pass over. Warning: Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter and breaks pagination. The 'offset' parameter is ignored when 'posts_per_page'=>-1 (show all posts) is used.

Comment: Thank you posting out an answer, it is also something I come across to decipher the issue but great for others to see your answer if they come across my same problem. Thanks again.